# Raspberry pi button delay time to a relay

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi

I am new to Raspberry pi and python and am having a bit of trouble with some code
I wish to push a button and have the gpio pin that corresponds to that button trigger a relay to turn on for a given amount of time then turn off. I have it working with the code below but by using the 'time.sleep(my-variable)' it holds up the raspberry pi for the duration of the time and i am unable to do anything else.
What i am after is the ability to push one button and get the relay to act for say 10 seconds and within those 10 seconds be able to press another button to fire another relay and do the same thing without tying up the pi

my code below first checks if input_state_LHS is equel to false, then clears the LCD display, writes text to the LCD on one line then on the next line it write the value of my variable(LHS_feedtime) then fires the relay with the time on the next line time.sleep, this is the bit i wish to be rid of but am unable to figure out the code to do it.

```
if input_state_LHS == False:
        ## calls the LCD_Clear function which has to be in the same folder as this file
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("LHS Feedtime",1,2)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(str(round(LHS_feedtime, 2)) + " sec" , 2,5)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )
        time.sleep(LHS_feedtime)
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Flatson Feeding", 1)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Systems", 2,4)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )
        menuitem = 0
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need is in the Python standard library class threading.Timer.  When you start a timer it launches another thread, which consists of a time delay followed by a call to a function that you specify.  In contrast to time.sleep() which stops your main thread at that point, with a Timer your main thread will keep going.

Here is roughly what you want:

```
from threading import Timer

def turn_off_lcd():
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Flatson Feeding", 1)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Systems", 2,4)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )

if input_state_LHS == False:
        ## calls the LCD_Clear function which has to be in the same folder as this file
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("LHS Feedtime",1,2)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(str(round(LHS_feedtime, 2)) + " sec" , 2,5)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )
        t = Timer(LHS_feedtime, turn_off_led)
        t.start()
        menuitem = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this will constantly loop the code until the 10 seconds have passed. But it will constantly print "10 seconds havent passed" (you can remove this line.) As you will notice, this code does not use the time.sleep() and so will not hold the script up.

```
import time

#Get the initial system time
timebuttonpressed = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
elapsedtime = time.strftime("%H%M%S")

while True:
    elapsedtime = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
    if input_state_LHS == False:
        #Get the new system time, but only set timesample2
        timebuttonpressed = time.strftime("%H%M%S")

        ## calls the LCD_Clear function which has to be in the same folder as this file
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("LHS Feedtime",1,2)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string(str(round(LHS_feedtime, 2)) + " sec" , 2,5)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )

    #Check if 10 seconds have passed
    if((int(elapsedtime) - int(timebuttonpressed)) == 10):
        timebuttonpressed = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
        mylcd.lcd_clear()
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Flatson Feeding", 1)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Systems", 2,4)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.input(12) )
        menuitem = 0

    print("10 seconds havent passed...")
```